# In qListView, items deleted are not getting updated in view

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt4

I have qListView populated with items which are actually filenames that I am reading from a folder.
Now, using context menu action "remove", I am deleting the corresponding file in the background.

The issue is the qListView, not getting updated ie. it is still showing the item that I have already remove.

My query is, how to refresh the view dynamically? I am new to MVC programming, was wondering if it is possible do it in model? Or, do I have to using recursive function to update views. BTW m using qAbstract list model and even tried currentItemChanged and dataChanged but nothing seems to work.

TestStepInstViewHdlr is the instance of QListView class:

```
TestStepInstViewHdlr.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
TestStepInstViewHdlr.show()
TestStepViewHdlr.stepSelected.connect(getTestStepName)
TestStepInstViewHdlr.itemSelectionChanged.connect(TestStepInstViewHdlr.getInstanceName)
TestStepInstViewHdlr.customContextMenuRequested.connect(TestStepInstViewHdlr.onContext)

def getInstanceName(self):
    index = self.selectedIndexes()
    val = ""
    valArray = []
    for i in index:
        val = i.data()
        valArray.append(val)
    print(valArray)
    return valArray

def onContext(self, position):
    instArray = []
    constHdlr = const.Constant()
    # Create a menu
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    rmvAction = menu.addAction("Remove")
    canAction = menu.addAction("Cancel")
    action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(position))
    if action == rmvAction:
        instArray =  self.getInstanceName()
        path = constHdlr.TEST_STEP_INSTANCE_PATH + StepName+"\\"
        for inst in instArray:
            path = path + inst
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                os.remove(path)

    if action == canAction:
        pass
```

My model is:

```
class TestStepInstListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, TestSteps = [], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__TestSteps = TestSteps

    def rowCount(self, parent = None):
        return len(self.__TestSteps)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            return self.__TestSteps[row]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable  | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        for i in range(rows):
            value = self.__TestSteps[position]
            self.__TestSteps.remove(value)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What is your model? Why are you not deleting the items from the model instead? The model should then handle deleting the file.

Comment: Hi Kuba, I updated model code.Model to deleted the files and update views, I need to check.

Comment: You are trying do something what is already done. See [QDirModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdirmodel.html).

Comment: Where do you make the call to `removeRows`? Is it actually executed?

Answer (score 1):

[QStandardItemModel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html#details)

Chirag if you are writing your own model, it will consume a lot of time. Instead check out **QStandardItemModel**, as it provides us with lots of things that are already implemented and we need to just use them in our code as per our requirements.

I am using this QStandardItemModel and have my own contextmenu.

```
self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
```

If I choose delete option  in my code, this piece of code will help us in deleting the item selected in our listview(i.e. to delete that particular row).

```
item_to_be_deleted = self.listView.selectionModel().currentIndex().data().toString()
            model = self.model
            for item in model.findItems(item_to_be_deleted):
                model.removeRow(item.row())
```

Comment: Thanks Juna for answering. But I used QFileSystemModel which is similar to (performance wise advance to) QDirModel as suggested by Marek R. And it is easy to manage and work like charm !!

Comment: @chirag was this code piece helpful for updating your listview dynamically..?